# MediaWiki showing HTML escaped div tag

Tags: mediawiki

I have just installed MediaWiki in my server.

When I try to create an article on the `Create Article` page, all the default `<div>` tags are being escaped and shown as text on the page, see screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of div tag showing as text]

Excerpt of article HTML rendered by MediaWiki:

```html
<div id="mw-content-text"><p>&lt;div class='noarticletext'&gt;
There is currently no text in this page.
You can <a href="/wiki/Special:Search/Mytestpage" title="Special:Search/Mytestpage">search for this page title</a> in other pages,
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because it was so minimal, you did not satisfy all the newline requirements for using `<div>` in a MediaWiki article. Specifically:

> `<div>` is a generic block container. Rules:
>
> `<div>` should be followed by a newline
>
> `</div>` should be preceded by a newline
>
> `</div>` followed by text on the same line, two newlines and text before `<div>` on the same line should be avoided (because the two newlines only produce a space)

From Help:HTML in wikitext, https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext#.3Cdiv.3E

### Recommendation

Fulfill the newline requirements, for example in MediaWiki source for that article, write:

```
<div class="noarticletext">
This is on a new line, fulfilling the rules, so this div should now render.
</div>
```

Preview or save to view the results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately these div tags only shown in all the default system pages. Like NoArticle page, Special Message page. and so on. For pages that I have already been created, they does not appear..